# How to change the accordian animation while closing using angular2 and CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an accordion.. while opening it is opening slowly but while closing its closing very fasting within fraction of ms range. Kindly help me to change the animation while closing.
I am here by sharing my HTML and css code, 
Please help.

**HTML Code:**

```
<accordion>
 <accordion-group #groupUser class="outer admin">
    <div accordion-heading >
           ABCD
      <i class="pull-right" [ngClass]="{'closeArrow': groupUser?.isOpen, 'openArrow': !groupUser?.isOpen}"></i>
     </div>
     <div layout="row" class="row listing-element tracking-listing">
    <div layout="row">                     
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Car</div>
     </div>
     </div>
      <div layout="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Bike</div>
      <div layout="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Auto</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

CSS:

```
 #wd-faq .outer .panel-collapse .panel-body {
        margin-top: 18px;
        border: 0;
        background-color: blue;
        -webkit-animation:all 150ms;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    @keyframes all {
        0% {
            height:0px;
        }
        100% {
            height:auto;
        }
    }
```

The CSS i pasted above is of opening accordion. Help me for Closing accordion.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can try with max-height instead but I guess what you need is a fixed height (or max-height)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. max-height shouldnt b fixed, because as the entries goes on adding it must expand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in yout HTML Code

> HTML CODE

```
    <accordion>
         <accordion-group #groupUser class="outer admin">
            <div accordion-heading >
                   ABCD
              <i class="pull-right" [ngClass]="{'closeArrow': groupUser?.isOpen, 'openArrow': !groupUser?.isOpen}"></i>
             </div>
    <div class="slideInDown">
    </div>
<accordion-heading>
<accordion>
```

and change your CSS with these codes

> CSS

```
    .slideInDown{
 -webkit-animation-name: slideInDown;
 animation-name: slideInDown;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 80ms;
 animation-duration: 80ms;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInDown {
 0% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 visibility: visible;
 }
 100% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 transform: translateY(0);
 }
}
@keyframes slideInDown {
 0% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 visibility: visible;
 }
 100% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 transform: translateY(0);
 }
}
```

I dont know it satisfies your requirement properly or not but you can try once.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. This is better compared to what i had, is there any idea for closing?

Comment: You can check this link for different types of animations http://www.theappguruz.com/tag-tools/web/CSSAnimations/.

Comment: Similarly try with something like this <div class="slideOutUp" [ngClass]="{slideOutUp: groupUser?.isOpen, 'slideInDown':  !groupUser?.isOpen}">

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is with the animation. It's not the best choice for the toggle animation. If you check your animation you can see there it is only an open animation. You can use two animation or only one and make it reverse direction with css but it would be pain in the ass and also produce a terrible code. But you can use transition which is works perfectly and it is looks more better and produce less code.

Here is the code:

CSS:

There is an .accordion class which is 0 at the beginning and I have a transition which 2s long. I use max-height because auto won't work and it will be as high as the content when it's opened.

```
.accordion {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 2s;
}
.accordion.open {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

In the HTML i have a click event on a button which open the div. It has a toggle function. On the accordion div there is an ngClass with the open class and with an isOpen boolean.

```
<button (click)="toggle()">OPEN</button>
<div class="accordion" [ngClass]="{'open': isOpen}">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

TypeScript code:

This is a simple code for checking the state of the accordion.

```
isOpen:boolean = false;
public toggle() {
  if(this.isOpen) {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }else {
    this.isOpen = true;
  }
}
```

And that's all. I hope you understand my English :D.

And here is a [WORKING PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/B2nnGeqfabTSjm232QvI?p=preview).

Comment: Nagy: Thanks for replying. I will try and tell you the update

Comment: i need the same way it is working in your plunker.. But i am not able to adjust that with my code. Can u please help me to link with my code. and max height should b auto because as the entries goes long it must take so

Comment: Can u help me with any other solutions please

Comment: If I am right your accordion is a custom component?

Comment: I try to adjust to your code as accurately as I can. So the accordion-heading div should be the button which open the content, so that one contains the (click)="open()" function. Your listing-element div should get the [ngClass]="{'open': isOpen}". That is the maximum help I can give from the code you share. Try to figure out how these connected to each other and you will be to adjust it with your code. On the other hand height: auto because it is not an animatable property :(. So you can use max-height and set it to something greater than it will ever get.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is going to get many entries based on users so im not getting to what height it can be adjusted. Without max-height it is not working i tried with ur plunker as well.